# What does it mean when a scorecard mentions 3.6 in the Overs column in cricket?

Tags: cricket

When I look at a scorecard I see a column "O (overs)" mentions 3.6 or 7.0. What does it mean? How to understand this statistic? I know that "overs" mean that player makes 6 legal deliveries to the batsman, but I don't understand what 3.6 stands for.

Comment: May be they are telling u that its 6th ball of 3rd over.. don't take my answer seriously because I am just kidding or prevailing my first thought.. :)

Answer (score 1):

An over in cricket consists of 6 legal deliveries. The figures you're referring to (i.e. 3.6 and 7.0), are merely forms of notation intended to record or count the exact number of balls that have been delivered throughout the course of an innings. '2.1', for example, literally means '2 overs and 1 ball delivered', making for a total of 13 legal deliveries. Likewise, '3.6' signifies 3 overs and 6 balls delivered (equivalent to 4 overs).

The values are often used to record either the total number of overs and balls delivered during the course of an innings, either by a team as a whole or a single bowler.

Comment: Of course during matches with 8-ball overs, 3.6 is not four complete overs.